# What is the antlr4 (v-4.1) equivalent form of the following grammar rule (written for antlr3 (v-3.2))?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlr4

What is the antlr4 (v-4.1) equivalent form of the following grammar rule (written for antlr3 (v-3.2))?

```
text
:   tag => (tag)!
|   outsidetag
;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is invalid in ANTLR 3:

```
text
:   tag => (tag)!
|   outsidetag
;
```

You probably meant the following:

```
text
 : (tag)=> (tag)!
 | outsidetag
 ;
```

where `( ... )=>` is a syntactic predicate, which has no ANTLR4 equivalent: [simply remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431158/syntactic-predicates-upgrading-from-antlr-3-to-antlr-4). As 280Z28 mentioned (and also explained in the previous link): *the lack of syntactic predicates is not a feature that was removed from ANTLR 4. It's a workaround for a weakness in ANTLR 3's prediction algorithm that no longer applies to ANTLR 4.*

The exlamation mark in v3 denotes to removal of a rule in the generated AST. Since [ANTLR4 does not produce AST's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823333/how-can-i-build-an-ast-using-antlr4), also just remove the exclamation mark.

So, the v4 equivalent would look like this:

```
text
 : tag
 | outsidetag
 ;
```

Comment: You might clarify that the lack of syntactic predicates is not a feature that was removed from ANTLR 4. It's a workaround for a weakness in ANTLR 3's prediction algorithm that no longer applies to ANTLR 4.

Comment: @280Z28, true, I was a bit lazy, and this is already mentioned in your answer I linked to. Anyway, edited my answer.

Comment: Simply ignore would mean? What would be the output of toStringTree() called through root? Will that replace an occurrence of tag with a space?